# Is it possible to set a http proxy & port on a personal hotspot connection

Tags: wifi-hotspot, proxy

When an Android Phone is connected to a WiFi network, there is an option to set a manual HTTP proxy and port.

When user has created an personal WiFi hotspot ( sharing the cellular connection) there is no user setting where I can setup a manual HTTP proxy/port for the WiFi hotspot's connection, and the cellular HTTP proxy settings are ignored. I want HTTP from devices connected to the hotspot to be routed to an HTTP proxy/port.

Is there a way that I can achieve this?